# Give CSS STYLE to RadioButtonList

Tags: css

I have Page in which I use a **RadiobuttonList** that is in an HTML table. I have given a CSS style to **table** and **td**. I have also given a CSS style to **RadioButtonList**, but it doesn't take its style from **RadioButtonList** - it takes it from **td**. Is there any way to make **RadioButtonList** follow the style of **RadioButtonList** instead of **td**?

Comment: Provide an example and some code, please.

Comment: Could you please specify which styles you are applying, and which ones specifically are not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really difficult to style radio buttons, checkboxes, and selects consistently across multiple browsers. Your best bet is to try using some js like this jQuery plugin - [Fancy Checkboxes](http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2006/06/11/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you talk about styling an `asp:RadioButtonList`.

Add a CssClass on your `asp:RadioButtonList` and define it in your CSS

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" CssClass="radiobuttonlist">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Item1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Item2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Item3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

CSS

```
.radiobuttonlist                    { }
.radiobuttonlist tr                 { }
.radiobuttonlist tr td              { }
.radiobuttonlist tr td input        { }
.radiobuttonlist tr td label        { }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ability to style radio buttons via CSS is limited. How they look varies from browser to browser and OS to OS. You're best to leave them alone unless you want to replace them with a scripted version.